# Why is the average number of steps for finding an item in an array N/2?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, linear-search

Could somebody explain why the  average number of steps for finding an item in an unsorted array data-structure is N/2?

Comment: Well, it actually depends on the algorithm you will follow to search your array. Please mention which algorithm you are using.

Comment: I mighy be missing the obvious, but if you're checking each element one by one until you find the one you're looking for, you will obviously have checked N/2 elements on average. (Provided that you're looking for a random element.)

Comment: This is a surprisingly good question - I can't seem to prove that it's true, since if you choose the array elements from some weird distribution it doesn't necessarily give you N/2 steps on average.

Comment: @templatetypedef: It's not so difficult, you just have to remember some probability formulas.

Comment: @ruslik: If you assume that the sought item occurs exactly once, and that its probability is uniformly distributed...

Comment: @ruslik- I managed to come up with a proof with some pretty strong assumptions on the structure of the array (a random permutation of a list of unique values).  This seems like way too strong of an assumption, though, and I was hoping to find something a bit weaker as a precondition.

Comment: @templatetypedef it's not what distribution the elements are but what elements you search. To get the N/2 result you assume that you search for an element chosen in random from the array with uniform probability.

Comment: @ybungalobill- That's true, but if the array contains duplicates then the element you end up finding might have the same value as the one you want to search for but not be the exact element you picked.  As an extreme case, if all the values are the same the search time is always 1, even if you want to search for the kth value of the array.

Answer (score 4):

This really depends what you know about the numbers in the array.  If they're all drawn from a distribution where all the probability mass is on a single value, then on expectation it will take you exactly 1 step to find the value you're looking for, since every value is the same, for example.

Let's now make a pretty strong assumption, that the array is filled with *a random permutation of distinct values*.  You can think of this as picking some arbitrary sorted list of distinct elements and then randomly permuting it.  In this case, suppose you're searching for some element in the array that actually exists (this proof breaks down if the element is not present).  Then the number of steps you need to take is given by X, where X is the position of the element in the array.  The average number of steps is then E[X], which is given by

```
E[X] = 1 Pr[X = 1] + 2 Pr[X = 2] + ... + n Pr[X = n]
```

Since we're assuming all the elements are drawn from a random permutation,

```
Pr[X = 1] = Pr[X = 2] = ... = Pr[X = n] = 1/n
```

So this expression is given by

```
E[X] = sum (i = 1 to n) i / n = (1 / n) sum (i = 1 to n) i = (1 / n) (n)(n + 1) / 2
     = (n + 1) / 2
```

Which, I think, is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Good answer. I was thinking of the case where bucket sort has been run initially and you have enough memory to store all items, in order, and it would take one step. I didn't think of the dirac delta.

Comment: If you want a weaker condition you just need that the probabilities that X lies in [0, N/2) and X lies in [N/2, N) to be equal.

Comment: @GregS- Is that really a sufficiently strong condition?  Why does that split work versus any of the other splits you could make?

Comment: @GregS nope. e.g. array = { 1, ..., N}. You search for N/2-1 with probability 1/2 and for N with probability 1/2. This satisfies your conditions but gives ~3N/4 expected time.

Answer (score 1):

The question as stated is just wrong. [Linear search may perform better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search#Non-uniform_probabilities).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler example that shows why the average is N/2 is this:

Assume you have an unsorted array of 10 items:  `[5, 0, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 4, 6]`.  This is all the digits `[0..9]`.

Since the array is unsorted (i.e. you know nothing about the order of the items), the only way you can find a particular item in the array is by doing a linear search:  start at the first item and go until you find what you're looking for, or you reach the end.

So let's count how many operations it takes to find each item.  Finding the first item (5) takes only one operation.  Finding the second item (0) takes two.  Finding the last item (6) takes 10 operations.  The total number of operations required to find all 10 items is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10, or 55.  The average is 55/10, or 5.5.

The "linear search takes, on average, N/2 steps" conventional wisdom makes a number of assumptions.  The two biggest are:

1. The item you're looking for is in the array.  If an item isn't in the array, then it takes N steps to determine that.  So if you're often looking for items that aren't there, then your average number of steps per search is going to be much higher than N/2.
2. On average, each item is searched for approximately as often as any other item.  That is, you search for "6" as often as you search for "0", etc.  If some items are looked up significantly more often than others, then the average number of steps per search is going to be skewed in favor of the items that are searched for more frequently.  The number will be higher or lower than N/2, depending on the positions of the most frequently looked-up items.

Comment: But why the average is N/2 rather than (N+1)/2? In your example, you've summed up 1+...+10 and divided by the number 10 which 55/10=5.5. The preceding result can be determined by (N+1)/2=5.5 **not** N/2.

Comment: @CroCo: Read "N/2" as "approximately N/2". When we're doing this type of calculation, the idea is to approximate the number of steps, not come up with an exact number. Or see Rafe's answer, which explains it slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

While I think templatetypedef has the most instructive answer, in this case there is a much simpler one.

Consider permutations of the set {x1, x2, ..., xn} where n = 2m.  Now take some element xi you wish to locate.  For each permutation where xi occurs at index m - k, there is a corresponding mirror image permutation where xi occurs at index m + k.  The mean of these possible indices is just [(m - k) + (m + k)]/2 = m = n/2.  Therefore the mean of all all possible permutations of the set is n/2.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple reformulation of the question:

What would be the limit of

```
lim (i->inf) of (sum(from 1 to i of random(n)) /i)
```

Or in C:

```
int sum = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < LARGE_NUM; i++) sum += random(n);
sum /= LARGE_NUM;
```

If we assume that our `random` have even distribution of values (each value from `1` to `n` is equally likely to be produced), then the expected result would be `(1+n)/2`.